# Родительские, прародительские и собственные видимости сущностей

Tags: laravel

Я пишу интернет-витрину на laravel v5.8.
Есть два уровня категорий, в подкатегории находятся товары. Путь к определенному товару: category -> subcategory -> product.
Необходимо реализовать возможность скрывать/показывать как товар, так подкатегорию и категорию.

Товар не должен добавляться в коллекцию, если видимость его, либо его родительской или прародительской категорий равны FALSE.

[image: Для наглядности вывод видимостей для товаров:]

Есть у меня подозрение, что изобретаю велосипед из зефира и палок. Вот, что я уже пробовал:

- использовать свойство 'visible' - метод setVisible конфликтует с методом предка модели. поменял на 'seeable'.
- создавать дополнительные поля в таблицах categories ('seeable', 'parent_seeabe') и producrs ('seeable', 'parent_seeabe', 'grandparent_seeable') - не комильфо, как мне кажется, дублировать данные.
- в таблицах categories и producrs использовать только свойство seeable, при получении коллекции категорий добавлять проверку на видимость родительской категории, используя accesor getParentSeeableAttribute: [*->where('parent_seeable', '=', 'on')*]

accesor getParentSeeableAttribute, получающий свойство 'seeable' родителя:

```
// app/Category.php

/**
* Accessor
* in controller or blade using snake-case: $category->parent_seeable!!!
*/
public function getParentSeeableAttribute()
{
    return $this->parent->get()->max('seeable');
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно реализовать задуманное.

Comment: Вы хотите сделать вывод категорий, подкатегорий и продуктов подкатегорий? Я правильно вас понял? И вы хотите сделать возможность прятать это все? Чтобы некоторые подкатегории или продукты не были видны ?

Comment: Да. Спасибо за уточнение. Поправил формулировку вопроса.